# Access data from excel in single column using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel

[My input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tcyJ.png)

1. I have attached an Excel column with few rows
2. Number 445.04 is repeated thrice in this column.
3. I have to write a logic in java which will help me iterate through this column with 200+ rows and add these type of values will result in zero.
4. The numbers can be different, take up any value where the possibility of them when operated can result in zero.
5. [Here's another picture with different scenerio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlFZY.png)
6. In the above, 10 and -3-7 when added can be made zero and also 5 and -5 can also be made zero.
   7.How can i write the code which can access a single column for this type of scenario? Leave a comment if anything additional is required.

This is what I'm trying to achieve...the output can be printed on console of the IDE instead in the excel itself

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMoBV.png)

---

```
    Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
    List<Double> posValue = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> negValue = new ArrayList<Double>();
    while(iterator.hasNext())//goes down the row, until there is nothing
    {    
        Row nexRow = iterator.next();
        if(nexRow.getRowNum()!=0){
            value = nexRow.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();

            if(value>0){
                posValue.add(value);
            }
            else if(value <0){
                //System.out.println("ehre");
                negValue.add(value);
            }
        }
        Iterator<Double> pIterator = posValue.iterator();
        Iterator<Double> nIterator = negValue.iterator();

        for(int i = 0; i<posValue.size();i++){
            for(int j=0; j<negValue.size(); j++){
                //System.out.println(negValue.get(j));
                result= posValue.get(i)+negValue.get(j);
            }
        }
        if(result==0){
            System.out.println(result+"    "+nexRow.getRowNum());
        }
        workbook.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

I thought of this because I have to calculate the values on the basis their signs and make it zero.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate though the rows using a loop of some kind. This should help you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String excelFilePath = "Book1.xlsx";
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    XSSFSheet firstSheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
    iterator.next();// skip the header row
    Double result = 0.0;

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row nextRow = iterator.next();
        result += nextRow.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
    }
    System.out.println(result);

    workbook.close();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Excel doc.

[image]

Comment: Hi, your code shows me how to iterate through the rows but each time the result of the row is just becoming the addition with the previous one. Can you help me figuring out why? Check the code where i've separated the the positive and negative numbers please. @Piyush

Comment: Do you want to separately add the positive and negative numbers?

Comment: Please go through the updated code and check the "expected result" image, that's what i'm trying to achieve..thanks!

Comment: @Akshaykumar I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you let me know exact excel input and the ouput? I can help you on that.  Do you want to just add all  the numbers? If so, why are you interested in them being positive or negative?

Comment: Only add the numbers which can be subtracted to zero. If a column contains 400,200, -600,300,... (and this is sequential order) first I should be able to add 400 and 200 and then add it with -600 so that the result will be zero in any of the rows. Assume that there are many different numbers in the column, I'm trying to make as many rows as possible to zero. the input data image is just a small screenshot of the excel sheet which has 200+ rows and many different values and expected result to be on the console of eclipse IDE(just by a sysout). I hope you understood..@Piyush

Answer (score 0):

```
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    double addedValue = 0;
    double value = 0;
    List<Double> value1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double result =0;
    Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
    List<Double> posValue = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double negValue = 0;
    while(iterator.hasNext())//goes down the row, until there is nothing
    {    
        Row nexRow =iterator.next();
        if(nexRow.getRowNum()!=0)
        {
            value = nexRow.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
            value1.add(value);
            for(int i=0; i<value1.size();i++)
            {
                //For storing all the values 
                addedValue=value1.get(i);


                /* Checking if the values are negative or not 
          If it is, then convert it to positive */
                if(addedValue<0)
                {                         
                    negValue=Math.abs(value1.get(i));
                }
            }
            /*checking for the numbers which can be operated to make it zero
               and then displaying the row numbers which have been cancelled out*/

            if(addedValue==negValue)
            {
                result = addedValue-negValue;
                nexRow.getCell(3).setCellValue(0.0);
                System.out.println(result+"  Matched rows--> "+nexRow.getRowNum());

            }
        }
        workbook.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

}

This is what I was trying to achieve. It will make the rows zero where the values can be operated on.  @Piyush